# Show that $(\binom{p^2}{p} -p ) $ is divisible by $p^5$, for every prime number $p, p\ge 5$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

Show that $(\binom{p^2}{p} -p ) $ is divisible by $p^5$, for every prime number $p, p\ge 5$.

I have a combinatorics problem, and this is what it reduces to. I am not quite sure how to link the fifth power in divisiblity.

Edit: I have shown this is equivalent to $$(p-1)!\cdot(\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{i}) \equiv 0 \pmod  {p^2}$$

Comment: Can you give the original problem?

Comment: Show that the number of ways to choose p positions on a p x p matrix, such that the p elements aren't all on the same row, is divisible by p^5

Comment: :P that's what i was thinking.

Comment: was it a chessboard problem ?

Comment: Yes, it was a chessboard problem.

Comment: The congruence $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac 1i\equiv0\pmod{p^2}$ is Wolstenholme's theorem.

Comment: This is a particular case of Remark 17 in [Mestrovic, arXiv:1111.3057v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3057v2). That said, a proof doesn't seem to appear in the literature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since
  $$ \binom{p^2}p = \frac{p^2(p^2-1)\dotsb(p^2-(p-1))}{1\cdot2\dotsb(p-1)p}, $$
we want to show that 
  $$ \frac{(p^2-1)\dotsb(p^2-(p-1))}{1\cdot2\dotsb(p-1)} \equiv 1 \pmod{p^4}; $$
that is,
  $$ (p^2-1)\dotsb(p^2-(p-1)) \equiv (p-1)! \pmod{p^4}. $$
Opening the parentheses in the LHS and observing that $(-1)(-2)\dotsb(-(p-1))=(p-1)!$, it remains to show that the sum of all $p-1$ terms divisible by $p^2$ but not by $p^4$ is $0$ mod $p^4$; that is, considering the polynomial
  $$ P(x) := (x-1)(x-2)\dotsb(x-(p-1)), $$
we want to show that the coefficient of the linear term of this polynomial is $0$ mod $p^2$.

To this end we make two observations. The first is nearly trivial: 
  $$ P(p-x) = P(x). \tag{1} $$
The second observation is that the polynomial $P(x)-(x^{p-1}-1)$ has degree at most $p-2$, while the value of this polynomial at every integer point is divisible by $p$ (hint: use Wilson's theorem for $x\equiv 0\pmod p$); consequently, 
  $$ P(x) = (x^{p-1}-1) + pQ(x), \tag{2} $$
where $Q$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients.

Substituting (1) into (2), we get
  $$ (p-x)^{p-1}-1+pQ(p-x) = x^{p-1}-1+pQ(x), $$
which, in view of $(p-x)^{p-1}\equiv x^{p-1}-(p-1)px^{p-2}\pmod{p^2}$, yields
  $$ pQ(p-x) \equiv (p-1)px^{p-2} + pQ(x) \pmod{p^2}; $$
that is,
  $$ Q(p-x) \equiv Q(x)-x^{p-2} \pmod p. $$
But $Q(p-x)\equiv Q(-x)\pmod p$; therefore
 $$ Q(-x)\equiv Q(x)-x^{p-2}\pmod p, $$
and it follows that the linear terms of $Q(-x)$ and $Q(x)$ vanish mod $p$. Now by (2), the linear term of $P$ is divisible by $p^2$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Well, not quite "all resulting summands". You have to add the ones with a $p^2$ together, and even then I'm not sure.

Comment: How do you see the next term is divisible by $p^4$ and not just $p^3$?

Comment: I think your answer (once corrected a bit) perfectly complements the other :)

Comment: @darijgrinberg: Took me a while, but seems eventually correct.

Comment: Nice work! Let me remark that your equality (2) (or, rather, the existence of a polynomial $Q\left(x\right) \in \mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]$ that satisfies it) is easier to prove by working over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ than by working over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed, over $\mathbb{F}_p$, the polynomial $\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)\cdots\left(x-\left(p-1\right)\right) - \left(x^{p-1} - 1\right)$ has degree $\leq p-2$ and has at least $p-1$ distinct roots (namely, the residue classes of $1, 2, \ldots, p-1$, because of Fermat's Little); thus, this polynomial must be $0$. Hence, ...

Comment: ... in $\mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]$, we have $\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)\cdots\left(x-\left(p-1\right)\right) \equiv x^{p-1} - 1 \mod p$. Wilson's theorem is not required for this, but instead can be obtained as an afterthought.

Answer (score 5):

It's sufficient to prove that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{i} \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}$.
Denote $S=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{i}$. Then, note that
$$
2S=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{1}{i}+\frac{1}{p-i}\right)=
p\cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{i(p-i)}.
$$
Hence, it's sufficient (since $p>3$) to prove that 
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{i(p-i)}\equiv 0\pmod p.
$$
However,
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{i(p-i)}\equiv -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{i^2}\pmod p.
$$
Since modulo $p$ we have $\{1,2,\ldots, p-1\}=\left\{\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\ldots, \frac{1}{p-1}\right\}$ we obtain 
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{i^2}\equiv \sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1} i^2=\frac{p(p-1)(2p-1)}{6}\equiv 0\pmod p
$$
for prime $p\geq 5$.
Thus, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{i^2} \equiv 0 \pmod {p}$ and so $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{i} \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}$, as desired.

Comment: I am not following what comes after the "Hence it is sufficient..."Why does $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{i(p-i)} \equiv 0$ mod $p$ imply $\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{1}{p} \equiv 0$ mod $p^2$? For $p>5$ of course

Comment: nevermind whoops